# Pages not showing in django CMS Admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

I've recently been following the [django CMS](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html) tutorial provided on their website, and after solving one or two tricky problems, I'm now stumped by the current system behaviour.

In the **Pages** section of the admin interface, none of the pages are being displayed. The interface currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlBqY.jpg

Even after clicking the Add Page button and filling in all the necessary fields, nothing is displayed. The following code is displayed in the HTML source of the page, which I think may be relevant to one of the pages:

```
<li id="page_2" class=" moveable"" rel="topnode">
<div class="cont ">
    <div class="col1">
            <a href="2/" class="title" title="edit this page">None</a>
            <a href="2/" class="changelink" title="edit this page">edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <span id="move-target-2" class="move-target-container" >
            <a href="#" class="move-target last-child" title="insert inside">↘</a>
        </span>
        <div class="col-softroot"><span class="icon softroot-icon" title="home"></span></div>
        <div class="col-language">
            <a href="2/?language=en" title="Edit this page in EN ">en</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-actions">
            <a href="#" class="move" title="Cut" id="move-link-2"><span>cut</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="copy" title="Copy" id="copy-link-2"><span>copy</span></a>
                    <a href="./add/?target=2&amp;position=last-child" class="addlink" title="Add Child" id="add-link-2"><span>add</span></a>
            <a href="2/delete/" title="Delete" class="deletelink"><span>delete</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-navigation">
            <label>
                <img alt="False" src="/static/admin/img/icon-no.gif" />
                <input type="checkbox" class="navigation-checkbox" name="navigation-2"  value="0" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-published">
            <label><img src="/static/admin/img/icon-yes.gif" alt="True" /></label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="publish-checkbox" name="status-2" checked="checked" value="1" title="Unpublish"/>
            <a href="./2/preview/?public=1" title="View on page" class="icon selector-add viewpage" id="view-page-2"><span>view</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-published">2013-07-11</div>
        <div class="col-view-perms"><span title="Restrictions: None"><img src="/static/admin/img/icon-unknown.gif" alt="None" /></span></div>
        <div class="col-lastchange">
        </div>
        <div class="col-creator">systems</div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

As you can see, various buttons like "Cut" and "Edit this page in EN" are contained within the code, but not displayed on the page.

For the sake of completeness, here is the relevant code from my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.conf import settings

   admin.autodiscover()

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
```

The pages I've created are definitely stored in the database, this problem is simply a case of them not being displayed.

```
 id | created_by | changed_by | parent_id |         creation_date         |         changed_date          |       publication_date        | publication_end_date | in_navigation | soft_root | reverse_id | navigation_extenders | published |    template     | site_id | login_required | limit_visibility_in_menu | level | lft | rght | tree_id | publisher_is_draft | publisher_public_id | publisher_state
----+------------+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+----------------+--------------------------+-------+-----+------+---------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------
  1 | systems    | systems    |           | 2013-07-11 11:34:18.216835+01 | 2013-07-11 11:34:18.216866+01 |                               |                      | f             | f         |            |                      | f         | template_1.html |       1 | f              |                          |     0 |   1 |    2 |       1 | t                  |                     |               1
  3 | systems    | systems    |           | 2013-07-11 11:42:45.476683+01 | 2013-07-11 11:42:45.47671+01  | 2013-07-11 11:42:19.135606+01 |                      | f             | f         |            |                      | t         | template_1.html |       1 | f              |                          |     0 |   1 |    2 |       3 | f                  |                   2 |               0
  2 | systems    | systems    |           | 2013-07-11 11:42:24.136515+01 | 2013-07-11 11:42:45.515485+01 | 2013-07-11 11:42:19.135606+01 |                      | f             | f         |            |                      | t         | template_1.html |       1 | f              |                          |     0 |   1 |    2 |       2 | t                  |                   3 |               0
(3 rows)
```

Thanks. Do let me know if there's anything else I can include to help find a solution.

Comment: are there any javascript errors? what version are you running?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't checked the console! Yeah, jQuery can't be found, which isn't ideal. In the process of rectifying the situation now, must be a problem with paths...

Comment: Solved. Thanks! Will answer the question in six hours.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a trailing slash to ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX so that it reads:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX - '/static/admin/'
```